# Is there a special way to do faceting on numeric fields in Lucene?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net, faceted-search

In an application using Lucene.Net, I have a numeric field that stores integers. The cardinality of the values is rather low (typically less than 20-30 different values).

I'd like to do a faceted search over this field (using `SimpleFacetedSearch` from the contrib package), that is I want the numbers of hits per distinct value.

Currently I'm storing a copy of the value as-is in an additional text field and I run the faceted search over this text field. This returns the correct results.

However, is this the way to go or is there a special way to do faceted search over NumericFields?

Note: because of the low cardinality I might consider setting the precision-step to int.MaxValue so that there's only one term per value. I suppose that in that case I could simple do the faceted search on the numeric field itself and decode the value manually using `NumericUtils.PrefixCodedToInt()`. Is this correct or will there be complications? My tests so far showed that it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Storing the values for facets in a separate field sounds logical. A numeric field can be thought of as a modified value, like string fields may have stemming and synonym expansion applied to them. One field for searching and one for facets is okay in these cases.

You could calculate facets on the mangled field (generated by NumericField), and call `PrefixCodedToInt` as you describe, and the same result. This would reduce index size (no need to store the numeric value, or index it separately). It may also reduce io load since you can read the values from the term index instead of seeking the documents on the hard drive, but this depends a lot on index size, file system cache, etc.